# In an object nesting key-value pairs, how to convert a single-value array into just the value itself?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given an array that nests inner objects which have key-value pairs, I want to convert single-element-arrays to just the value itself.

So let's say that we have the following `albums` array:

```js
const albums = [
    {
        "band": ["beetles"],
        "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
        "year": [1969]
    },
    {
        "band": [ "coldplay"],
        "album": ["Parachutes"],
        "year": [2000]
    },
    {
        "band": ["nirvana"],
        "album": ["nevermind"],
        "year": [1991]
    }
]
```

Since all the arrays are single-values, I would like to convert this entire `albums` object to:

```js
// desired output
[
    {
        "band": "beetles",
        "album": "yellow_submarine",
        "year": 1969
    },
    {
        "band": "coldplay",
        "album": "Parachutes",
        "year": 2000
    },
    {
        "band": "nirvana",
        "album": "nevermind",
        "year": 1991
    }
]
```

I've seem lots of posts discussing the *opposite* (i.e., how to convert a single value into an array), but could not find an answer to this current question. Maybe I'm not using the correct search terms...

Comment: Do you want to change the objects in-place, or create new objects?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thanks. I'd like to create a new object which like the desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Map `albums` to a new array of objects, use a `unArray` method within the `map` -lambda

```js
const albums = [{
    "band": ["beetles"],
    "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
    "year": [1969]
  },
  {
    "band": ["coldplay"],
    "album": ["Parachutes"],
    "year": [2000]
  },
  {
    "band": ["nirvana"],
    "album": ["nevermind"],
    "year": [1991]
  }
];

// Note: for a true copy of albums and its arrays,
// the values must be spreaded (e.g. ...album.band)
const noArrays = albums.map(album => {
  const unArray = v => v.length === 1 ? v.shift() : v;
  return { ...{},
    band: unArray(...album.band),
    album: unArray(...album.album),
    year: unArray(...album.year)
  };
});

console.log(noArrays);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

If the keys of the `albums` entries are not (all) known, using a [reducer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for all `album` entries would be more generic:

```js
const albums = [{
    "band": ["beetles"],
    "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
    "year": [1969]
  },
  {
    "band": ["coldplay"],
    "album": ["Parachutes"],
    "year": [2000]
  },
  {
    "band": ["nirvana"],
    "album": ["nevermind"],
    "year": [1991]
  }
];

// Note: for a true copy of albums and its arrays,
// the values ust be spreaded (i.e ...value)
const noArrays = albums.map( album => {
  const unArray = v => v.length === 1 ? v.shift() : v;
  return Object.entries(album).reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => 
    ({...acc, [key]: unArray(...value)}), {});
});

console.log(noArrays);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a new array of new objects, you'd use `map` along with creating new objects unwrapping their values. You have a couple of options for how to handle the objects. You could use `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries`:

```
const updatedAlbums = albums.map(album =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(album).map(([key, value]) => [key, value[0]])
    )
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const albums = [
    {
        "band": ["beetles"],
        "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
        "year": [1969]
    },
    {
        "band": [ "coldplay"],
        "album": ["Parachutes"],
        "year": [2000]
    },
    {
        "band": ["nirvana"],
        "album": ["nevermind"],
        "year": [1991]
    }
];

const updatedAlbums = albums.map(album =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(album).map(([key, value]) => [key, value[0]])
    )
);

console.log(updatedAlbums);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Or you could use an inner loop to avoid intermediary arrays:

```
const updatedAlbums = albums.map(album => {
    const newAlbum = {};
    for (const key in album) {
        if (Object.hasOwn(album, key)) {
            newAlbum[key] = album[key][0]; // Unwrapping the value
        }
    }
    return newAlbum;
});
```

Live Example:

```js
const albums = [
    {
        "band": ["beetles"],
        "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
        "year": [1969]
    },
    {
        "band": [ "coldplay"],
        "album": ["Parachutes"],
        "year": [2000]
    },
    {
        "band": ["nirvana"],
        "album": ["nevermind"],
        "year": [1991]
    }
];

// Quick-and-dirty polyfill for environments that don't have `Object.hasOwn` yet
if (!Object.hasOwn) {
    Object.hasOwn = Function.prototype.call.bind(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty);
}

const updatedAlbums = albums.map(album => {
    const newAlbum = {};
    for (const key in album) {
        if (Object.hasOwn(album, key)) {
            newAlbum[key] = album[key][0]; // Unwrapping the value
        }
    }
    return newAlbum;
});

console.log(updatedAlbums);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This changes the value in place rather than creating a new dictionary with the final result.

```
for (var i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
   for (var key in albums[i]) {
      albums[i][key] = albums[i][key][0];
   }
}
```

Comment: ```albums[0]["band"]``` is ```["beetles"]```, but ```albums[0]["band"][0]``` is not ```"beetles"```, but rather ```"b"```? I thought that ```"b"``` would be yielded from ```albums[0]["band"][0][0]```?

Comment: I ran this on OP's original dictionary with length-1 arrays, and ```albums[i][key]``` shows as ```"beetles"``` rather than ```["beetles"]``` in the console/window, perhaps because of some automatic cleansing when displaying length-1 arrays that JavaScript may perform that I'm unaware of. However, ```albums[i][key]``` is actually ```["beetles"]```, and ```albums[i][key][0]``` always yields ```"beetles"``` for me in the console. I can't replicate having ```albums[i][key][0]``` yield ```"b"```  alone.

Comment: My bad, I was looking at the wrong code block in the question!

Comment: No, thank you for reaching out! I'm new to JS so I appreciate the effort to help.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it Simple! You can achieve this by just using [Array.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) method.

**Working Demo :**

```js
const albums = [
    {
        "band": ["beetles"],
        "album": ["yellow_submarine"],
        "year": [1969]
    },
    {
        "band": [ "coldplay"],
        "album": ["Parachutes"],
        "year": [2000]
    },
    {
        "band": ["nirvana"],
        "album": ["nevermind"],
        "year": [1991]
    }
];

albums.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    obj[key] = obj[key].length === 1 ? obj[key].toString() : obj[key]
  });
});

console.log(albums);
```